# Find $\sin x \cos x$ if $\sin x = 4 \cos x$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> If $\sin x = 4 \cos x$, find $(\sin x)( \cos x)$.

I feel like this is a silly question, and I think I am overthinking this. Can someone give me a hint on how to start? Would finding x be effective or would it be too messy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Maybe starting with $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ is helpful :)

Comment: $5cos^{2} x = 1$ = $cos^{2} x = \frac{1}{5}$, then find x from there?

Comment: @Mathy Person you don't need to find x, you want $\sin x \cos x = 4 \cos^2x$. And you know $\cos^2x$ :-)

Comment: Ohh, I see now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

$a=\sin x\cos x=4\cos^2x=\dfrac{1}{4}\sin^2x$

Then $\cos^2x=\dfrac{a}{4}$ and $\sin^2x=4a$

---

$$
\sin x\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\sin2x=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}
$$

Comment: I got $(\sin x)( \cos x)=\dfrac{4}{17},$ is that correct?

Comment: @YunaKun Yes. With the second method it's easy, because the hypothesis says $\tan x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Rearranging gives
$$\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = 4.$$
This determines $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ (up to a common sign), and these can be computed with a reference triangle. In any case, the ambiguity in the sign disappears when we form the product $\sin x \cos x$.